# Transmision de datos

Tags: html, html5, imagen, hosting

Estoy investigando sobre el tema de la transmision de datos ya que estoy formando una página web pero todos los blogs que he encontrado te lo explican vagamente y sin entrar en mucho detalle, por lo que tengo 3 preguntas.

1-¿Si subo mis fotos a drive y lo cargo en la página consume transferencia de datos?

2-¿Cada vez que se clica en un link ya sea para abrir otra pagina del servidor o externa, consume transferencia de datos o solo una vez y eso se almacena en la caché?

3-¿Si creo un formulario de google el envio de datos también consume?

Muchas gracias

Comment: Hola Preguntador, aunque las preguntas que haces son interesantes y se ajustan bien al formato del sitio, trata de limitar las preguntas a una única duda. Además deberías aclarar algunos puntos: ¿a qué te refieres con consumir transferencia de datos? ¿Por parte del cliente o del servidor? ¿tienes alguna configuración de caché? Lee [ask] y completa el [tour] para más información

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Entiendo que te refieres a que tienes el tráfico limitado en tu hosting y no estamos hablando de los datos de tu smartphone. Es relativamente fácil de ver si te haces un esquema de las tres máquinas que están implicadas en tu ejemplo:

a) el ordenador del cliente web, el navegador o el usuario

b) la máquina del hosting, donde estará el servidor web y de bases de datos

c) el servidor de Google

Vamos con tus casos:

1) El hosting (b) envía una página a (a) y ésta se conecta a (c) sin hacer ya uso de (b). Un poco de (b) usas, llevando la web de (b) a (a), pero lo gordo se transfiere entre (a) y (c). Desde Google en (c) a tu página en (b), que yo sepa, no has comentado que hagas ninguna conexión. La ruta es (b)->(a)->(c)

2) Cada click que haces en (a), si te lleva a otra máquina que no sea (b) tal y como comentas, no consume tráfico en (b). Que se almacene lo que te bajes en la cache o no, no tiene nada que ver con (b)

3) Si el formulario lo tienes en Google (c), tampoco gastas tráfico. Únicamente el que se genere al visitar tu web (c) para obtener el enlace a Google (c), si es que ese enlace no lo envías por correo, por ejemplo.

Espero haberte ayudado, si te queda cualquier duda, deja un comentario

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder, ya lo tengo un poco más claro todo! Pero una pequeña duda en el 1ºcaso,¿ese poco que uso de (b) sería la llamada que hago de drive a la página? por lo que serían unos bytes no?

Comment: Acabo de modificar la respuesta, pregunta todo lo que necesites saber

Comment: Muchas gracias!